# Android textView.setText() throws exception

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app where I can put several times the same kind of layout in a `LinearLayout`.
The layout just has a `TextView` and i'm trying to use `setText` but this line of code doesn't seems to work.

I don't know how many layout I must add to the `LinearLayout` because it depends of how many drones (I have one layout/drone) the user will have upload to the app, so I made a function that read the text to put in the `TextView` from a `SharedPreference` and that also read the number of drones (so the number of layouts) in another `SharedPreferences`.

The `TextView` i'im putting the string in is from a layout named dronelayoutmain.
I tried sending just "test" in the `setText`, but it crashes anyway, so I think that android just can't find my `TextView`, but I don't really know why.

So here is the function I call in `OnCreate` that is supposed to add one layout for each drone I have

```
    public void affichagedrone(){
    LinearLayout mlineairelayout = (LinearLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.lineaireLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Context mContext;
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    SharedPreferences droneprefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("dronepref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences applimaindata = mContext.getSharedPreferences("applimaindata", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int nbdrone = applimaindata.getInt(String.valueOf(emplacementNbDrone),1);

    String string;

    TextView textViewnomConstructeurDrone;

    if (nbdrone !=0) {
        for(int i=0;i<nbdrone;i++) {
            textViewnomConstructeurDrone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNomConstructeur);

            string = droneprefs.getString(String.valueOf(i),"Fail");
            textViewnomConstructeurDrone.setText(string);

            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dronelayoutmain, null);
            // Add the new row before the add field button.
            mlineairelayout.addView(rowView);


        }
    }
}
```

And here is the layout i'm trying to put in the `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNomConstructeur"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/adddrone"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The function is supposed to check in applimaindata the number of layout to add, and then, in the for(), is supposed to set the Text of the `TextView` from the droneprefs file and then add the Layout to the main `LinearLayout`

Comment: When you mean "it crashed", you should post the logcat together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this TextView belongs in the newly inflated layout, you must find it after the layout is inflated:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nbdrone; i++) {
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dronelayoutmain, null);
    textViewnomConstructeurDrone = rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNomConstructeur);
    string = droneprefs.getString(String.valueOf(i),"Fail");
    textViewnomConstructeurDrone.setText(string);
    mlineairelayout.addView(rowView);
}
```